# How can a plaintiff dismiss their case in Maryland?

Tags: rules-of-court, maryland

How can a plaintiff in a Maryland District Court case dismiss their civil case after the issue was resolved with the defendant out-of-court?

What form is required?

Answer (score 5):

Voluntary Dismissal of a case in Maryland follows the [Maryland Revise Civil Procedure District Court Rule 3-506 - Voluntary Dismissal](https://casetext.com/rule/maryland-court-rules/title-3-maryland-rules-of-civil-procedure-district-court/chapter-500-trial/rule-3-506-voluntary-dismissal):

> (a) By Notice of Dismissal or Stipulation. Except as otherwise provided in these rules or by statute, a party who has filed a complaint, counterclaim, cross-claim, or third party claim may dismiss all or part of the claim without leave of court by filing
>
> - (1) a notice of dismissal at any time before the adverse party files a notice of intention to defend, or if the notice of dismissal specifies that it is with prejudice, at any time before judgment, or
> - (2) a stipulation of dismissal signed by all parties to the claim being dismissed.
>
> (b) Dismissal Upon Stipulated Terms. If an action is settled upon written stipulated terms and dismissed, the action may be reopened at any time upon request of any party to the settlement to enforce the stipulated terms through the entry of judgment or other appropriate relief.
>
> (c) By Order of Court. Except as provided in section (a) of this Rule, a party who has filed a complaint, counterclaim, cross-claim, or third party claim may dismiss the claim only by order of court and upon such terms and conditions as the court deems proper.
>
> (d) Effect on Claim. Unless otherwise specified in the notice of dismissal, stipulation, or order of court, a dismissal is without prejudice, except that a notice of dismissal operates as an adjudication upon the merits when filed by a party who has previously dismissed in any court of any state or in any court of the United States an action based on or including the same claim.
>
> (e) Effect on Counterclaim. If a counterclaim has been pleaded before the filing of a notice of dismissal or motion for voluntary dismissal, the dismissal of the action shall not affect the continued pendency of the counterclaim.
>
> (f) Costs. Unless otherwise provided by stipulation or order of court, the dismissing party is responsible for all costs of the action or the part dismissed.

There is a [form](https://www.courts.state.md.us/sites/default/files/court-forms/district/forms/civil/dccv021.pdf/dccv021.pdf) that explicitly refers to the 3-506 rule